# Java how to update a JSON object value and send it as a body to PUT request

Tags: java, json

I am trying to automate my REST service's PUT request and I am completely new to JAva. Here I am passing a PUT  body(in JSON format)  along with other headers.
I had created a Java class for PUT in which I have getters and setters and I am assigning values using setter and creating my PUT body and sending this PUT body in my PUT request.
My PUT body is something like this .  I am able to update "id" and "name" and create my body object but I am not sure how do I update the "versionname" and"number" under "versions" path?

```
{
    "versions": [
        {
            "versionname": "Test",
            "number": 1

        }
    ],
    "id": 89960004,
    "name": "TEST CES LIST4",


}
```

The class for PUT body is as below:

---

```
public class putBody {

public String id;
public String name;
public String versionName;
public String number;


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getversionName() {
    return versionName;
}

public void setversionName(String versionName) {
    this.versionName = versionName;
}
```

---

My question is how to update the "versionname" and "number" and create my putBody object. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is that a JSON String? or `JSONObject`?

Comment: Its a JSONObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your PutBody class must have a collection to keep your version data, according to the JSON output that you provided.

For this purpose, just create a Version class that will be used for every single version information:

```
public class Version {

    public String versionName;
    public String number;

    public String getVersionName() {
        return versionName;
    }

    public void setVersionName(String versionName) {
        this.versionName = versionName;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

Then, here is your PutBody class should be look like

```
public class PutBody {

    public String id;
    public String name;
    public List<Version> versions;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Version> getVersions() {
        return versions;
    }

    public void setVersions(List<Version> versions) {
        this.versions = versions;
    }

}
```

And here is how to fill it with data according to your example values :

```
List<Version> versions = new ArrayList<Version>();
    Version version = new Version();
    version.setVersionName("Test");
    version.setNumber("1");
    versions.add(version);

    PutBody putBody = new PutBody();

    putBody.setName("TEST CES LIST4");
    putBody.setId("89960004");
    putBody.setVersions(versions);
```

And the JSON Output :

```
{
  "id": "89960004",
  "name": "TEST CES LIST4",
  "versions": [
    {
      "versionName": "Test",
      "number": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

Google's Gson has great features for this purpose. You can easily convert Java instances to JSON and convert JSON strings back to Java instances.

Please check [that](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: Thank you so much for the resonse. I'll try this code and get back. I was wondering is there any inbuilt Java class/method which would do that like JSonObject etc ?

Comment: I updated the answer. You can use Gson to convert your instances to JSON string and convert them back.

Comment: Thank you so much!Also the code above which you provided with defining a class for version works too. So thanks again :)

Comment: Your welcome! You can set my answer as accepted then :)